# What is average pooling

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I was reading an article where they have a set of pages. For every page they extract a feature vector of dimention 300. Then they fuse these vectors into one vector by using a method called average pooling: Quoting : " to encode sets of pages into a compact document representation. The main idea consists of performing average pooling of page representations to obtain a single representation of an entire document"

P is the set of pages P = {p1,p2,p3,...,pn} and pi is the vector

F(p) = 1/|P| * Somme(pi) Such that p E P

Comment: Generally it's frowned upon to [cross-post a question across multiple sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101828/what-exactly-is-average-pooling). That said, [this site](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Pooling) may be of use to you.